# copying files from one S3 bucket to another S3 bucket sub folder

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a S3 bucket called "Test1" and another S3 bucket called "Test2". There are three sub folders inside Test2. Name of the sub folders are "RCA-test1/", "RCA-Test2/", "RCA-Test3/". I want to move the file from "Test1" bucket to Test2 bucket sub folder "RCA-test1". This is my code to achieve this:

```
 var listObjectsRequest = new Amazon.S3.Model.ListObjectsV2Request
        {
            BucketName = sourceBucketName
        };

        var listObjectsResponse = await sourceS3Client.ListObjectsV2Async(listObjectsRequest);

      foreach (var s3Object in listObjectsResponse.S3Objects)
        {
            if(!s3Object.Key.Contains("JSON"))
            {
            AmazonS3Client S3Client = new(accessKeyId.ToString(), secretAccessKey, RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
            await S3Client.CopyObjectAsync(sourceBucketName, s3Object.Key, destinationBucketName   , s3Object.Key);
            }
```

The above code copies the file from the source bucket to the destination bucket, but it does not copy the file in the subfolder. I tried to rewrite the code like this so that the file can be moved to the destination bucket:

```
  await S3Client.CopyObjectAsync(sourceBucketName, s3Object.Key, destinationBucketName + "/" + "RCA-test1/"   , s3Object.Key);
```

when I ran the code, I got this error:

Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception: 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.'. Below is the screenshot:

[image]

Not sure, what I am doing wrong. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you use `s3Object.Key` for both source and destination? I would expect the destination to have a different s3Object.Key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than modifying the **destination bucket name**:

```
  await S3Client.CopyObjectAsync(sourceBucketName, s3Object.Key, destinationBucketName + "/" + "RCA-test1/"   , s3Object.Key);
```

the code should be modifying the **destination key**:

```
  await S3Client.CopyObjectAsync(sourceBucketName, s3Object.Key, destinationBucketName, "RCA-test1/" + s3Object.Key);
```

The `Key` of an Amazon S3 object **includes the full path** of the object. Thus, to copy to a folder, simply include the folder name in the Key (eg `RCA-test1/file1.json`).